# how to save StringIO (pdf) data into file

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

I want to save `pdf` file which is located in external remote server with ruby. The `pdf` file is coming in `StringIO`. I tried saving the data with `File.write` but it is not working. I received the below error .

```
ArgumentError: string contains null byte
```

How to save now ?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
require 'stringio'

sio = StringIO.new("he\x00llo")

File.open('data.txt', 'w') do |f|
  f.puts(sio.read)
end


$ cat data.txt
hello
```

**Response to comment**:

Okay, try this:

```
require 'stringio'

sio = StringIO.new("\c2\xb5") 
sio.set_encoding('ASCII-8BIT')  #Apparently, this is what you have.

File.open('data.txt', 'w:utf-8') do |f|
  f.puts(sio.read)
end

--output:--
1.rb:7:in `write': "\xB5" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 (Encoding::UndefinedConversionError)
```

To get rid of that error, you can set the encoding of the StringIO to UTF-8:

```
require 'stringio'

sio = StringIO.new("\c2\xb5") 
sio.set_encoding('ASCII-8BIT')  #Apparently, this is what you have.

sio.set_encoding('UTF-8')  #Change the encoding to what it should be.

File.open('data.txt', 'w:UTF-8') do |f|
  f.puts(sio.read)
end
```

Or, you can use the File.open modes:

```
require 'stringio'

sio = StringIO.new("\c2\xb5") 
sio.set_encoding('ASCII-8BIT')  #Apparently, this is what you have.

File.open('data.txt', 'w:UTF-8:ASCII-8BIT') do |f|
  f.puts(sio.read)
end
```

But, that assumes the data is encoded in UTF-8.  If you actually have binary data, i.e. data that isn't encoded because it represents a .jpg file for instance, then that won't work.

Comment: doesn't worked. i got this `Encoding::UndefinedConversionError: "\xB5" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8` error

Comment: @ParitoshPiplewar,  1) What line of code produced that error? 2) What encoding is your pdf file?  3)What encoding do you want to use to write to the file?  It sounds like you have some binary data in your pdf file--in that case you can use `File.open(..., 'wb')`.

Comment: @ParitoshPiplewar, See the bottom of my answer for something else you can try.  But you are giving incomplete information, so I am just guessing.